# Is there a way to automatically use images from entries with Campaigns?

Tags: devdemon, social, devdemon-campaigns

I am using EE 2.10.1 and Campaigns 2.1.0a

Is there a way to automatically pull images from the entry being posted to FB, twitter, etc.?

For example, if I am using a Channel Images field in the entry, can I specify it to pull from that field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can setup in the channel settings to use a field to show the image. You can really use any template code in the pre-defined areas.

[image]